# How to get the result from an anonymous function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a simple script to geocode addresses.

```
var geocoder;
var departure;
var arrival;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function geocode(options) {
    var address = options.address.val() || null;
    var result = {};
    if (address) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                result.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                result.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            } else {
                result.lat = null;
                result.lng = null;
            }
        });
    }
}

function geocode_all() {
    departure = geocode({
        address: $('#departure')
    });
    //console.log(departure);

    arrival = geocode({
        address: $('#arrival')
    });
    //console.log(arrival);
}
```

I would like that my departure variable and my arrival variable to be object with the resulting latitude and longitude.

How should I proceed as my result variable is out of scope?

Thanks !

Comment: You could have a look at the promises pattern, which would fit your requirements here, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the function is anonymous, and it isn't scope; the problem is that the Google geolocation API is **asynchronous**. It's impossible for your `geocode` function to *return* its result; instead, just like Google's function, it must accept a callback that it calls back with the result *later*, when the result is known. (Or it can use callbacks indirectly, via the "promise" pattern, but the fundamental concept is the same.)

So, using a callback:

```
function geocode(options, callback) {
    //                    ^--- Accept the callback
    var address = options.address.val() || null;
    var result = {};
    if (address) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                result.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                result.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            } else {
                result.lat = null;
                result.lng = null;
            }
            callback(result); // <== Call it
        });
    }
}

// usage
geocode({/*...*/}, function(result) {
    // This gets called later, asynchronously, with the result
});
```

Or using a jQuery `Deferred`/`Promise`:

```
function geocode(options) {
    var d = new $.Deferred(); // <== Create the deferred
    var address = options.address.val() || null;
    var result = {};
    if (address) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                result.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                result.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            } else {
                result.lat = null;
                result.lng = null;
            }
            // Resolve the Deferred using your result
            d.resolve(result);
        });
    }

    // Return the Promise for the Deferred
    return d.promise();
}

// Usage
geocode({/*....*/}).done(function(result) {
    // This gets called later, asynchronously, with the result
});
```